# Pyramid and requests

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid, python-requests

Here is my server:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def post(request):
    print request
    return Response('temp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('measure','/measure')
    config.add_view(post,route_name='measure',request_method='POST')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

and client:

```
import json
import requests
import time

url = 'http://'localhost':8080/measure'
temp = 10
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

while True:
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(temp), headers=headers)
time.sleep(4)
```

and my question is: how can I see sent data on my browser, I searched it but couldn't find anything, I mean with `response(temp)`, it just gives an error like "global temp doesnt exist" or something like that.

Comment: There is no browser in your example, just two scripts, client and server. Client sends a POST request with '10' in its body, the server responds with string 'temp'. No browser anywhere. Please edit your question to add more details of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: yeah i know but for example config.add_route('measure','/measure')
    config.add_view(post,route_name='measure',request_method='GET') comman it should show that on browser, my problem is i cant response(the data i sent with client) just response(string) , do you know how can i do that ?